# Get device angle by using getOrientation() function

Tags: android, orientation, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I was using `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` to determine current angle of device but `TYPE_ORIENTATION` is deprecated on **API version 8**. In SensorManager manual it refers to `getOrientation()` function in order to use `TYPE_ORIENTATION`.

[**Here is the manual**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float%5C[%5C],%20float%5C[%5C]))

---

Here is my old code :

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Log.d("debug","Sensor Changed");
        if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
            Log.d("debug",Float.toString(event.values[0]));


            float mAzimuth = event.values[0];
            float mPitch = event.values[1];
            float mRoll = event.values[2];

            Log.d("debug","mAzimuth :"+Float.toString(mAzimuth));
            Log.d("debug","mPitch :"+Float.toString(mPitch));
            Log.d("debug","mRoll :"+Float.toString(mRoll));
        }

    }
```

I'm really confused about using `getOrientation()` function, can anyone please show me an example how to get the angles?

Answer (score 37):

You now use two sensors (ACCELEROMETER and MAGNETIC_FIELD) to get that information. See [blog post for more detail.](http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html)

```
public class CompassActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  Sensor accelerometer;
  Sensor magnetometer;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);    // Register the sensor listeners
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
  }

  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }

  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {  }

  float[] mGravity;
  float[] mGeomagnetic;
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
      mGravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
      mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
      float R[] = new float[9];
      float I[] = new float[9];
      boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
      if (success) {
        float orientation[] = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
        azimut = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the line below always returns false : boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);

Comment: Weird but check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/14224122/552902 seems like looping through the event values instead of a direct reference might fix it.

Comment: No, it is not returning false always, it returns true sometimes, approximately returns true every 10 seconds, but timing is not regular.

Comment: Sounds like a new question, sorry.

Comment: @fobus it returns false because most likely your device has no compass and hence you don't get magnetic values.

Comment: **WARNING:** the code above will garbage collect **A LOT** because of the new arrays within onSensorChanged(). The code here is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10291428/550471

Comment: It might be good to update this also now to point towards the 'Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR ' which is likely widely supported and can be much easier to use - good example here to steer people to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53408643/334402

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your second question. When you are registering your sensor listeners, change your code to read:

```
protected void onResume() {          
    super.onResume();          
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);          
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has a great demo app for orientation in their google-developer-training series called [TiltSpot](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-advanced/tree/master/TiltSpot). Because it has an Apache license, I've taken the liberty of turning it into a small library called [johnnylambada-orientation](https://github.com/johnnylambada/johnnylambada-orientation) that makes getting orientation as simple adding this to your activity:

```
        getLifecycle().addObserver(new OrientationReporter(this, (a, p, r) -> {
            Log.i("orientation","a="+a+" p="+p+" r="+r);
        }));
```

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.github.johnnylambada:johnnylambada-orientation:1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

**My Answer is for those who getting jumping values of heading. For further instruction let me know in the comment.**

```
Sensor accelerometer;
Sensor magnetometer;
private float[] mGravity = new float[3];
private float[] mGeomagnetic = new float[3];
private float[] Rv = new float[9];
private float[] I = new float[9];
```

**class MapsActivity**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, SensorEventListener{
```

**onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)**

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    synchronized (this) {
        float INITIAL_ALPHA = 0.97f;
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            mGravity[0] = INITIAL_ALPHA * mGravity[0] + (1 - INITIAL_ALPHA)
                    * event.values[0];
            mGravity[1] = INITIAL_ALPHA * mGravity[1] + (1 - INITIAL_ALPHA)
                    * event.values[1];
            mGravity[2] = INITIAL_ALPHA * mGravity[2] + (1 - INITIAL_ALPHA)
                    * event.values[2];
        }
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

            mGeomagnetic[0] = INITIAL_ALPHA * mGeomagnetic[0] + (1 - INITIAL_ALPHA)
                    * event.values[0];
            mGeomagnetic[1] = INITIAL_ALPHA * mGeomagnetic[1] + (1 - INITIAL_ALPHA)
                    * event.values[1];
            mGeomagnetic[2] = INITIAL_ALPHA * mGeomagnetic[2] + (1 - INITIAL_ALPHA)
                    * event.values[2];

            if (Math.abs(mGeomagnetic[2]) > Math.abs(mGeomagnetic[1])) {
                magStrength = Math.round(Math.abs(mGeomagnetic[2]));
            } else {
                magStrength = Math.round(Math.abs(mGeomagnetic[1]));
            }
        }

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rv, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float[] orientation = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(Rv, orientation);

            azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
            azimuth = (azimuth + 360) % 360;
            // Log.d(TAG, "azimuth (deg): " + azimuth);

            float degree = Math.round(azimuth);

            // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
            RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
                    currentDegree,
                    -degree,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);

            ra.setDuration(500);
            ra.setFillAfter(true);
            ra.setRepeatCount(0);

            binding.compassImage.startAnimation(ra);
            showDirection(degree);

            currentDegree = -degree;

        }
    }
}
```

**onAccuracyChanged**

```
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

**onResume()**

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mSensorManager == null) {
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = 
       mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = 
       mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    }
       mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, 
       SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
       mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, 
       SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}
```

**onPause()**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(MapsActivity.this);
}
```