# Android - Get orientation (Compass like) where phone is pointing at

Tags: java, android, maps, orientation, compass

I have an array of Marker (google maps markers) with longitude and latitude.
I want to create some sort of radar like view that'll display these markers as points where I'm looking toward their directions with an angle of 45°.

Do you guys have any idea how I can say "This marker is behind me, this marker is in front of me".
I guess I should apply cos and sin considering my orientation, but that's too blurry atm.

Hope you'll help :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already know your location and orientation. You can then calculate the directions of the array of markers using `computeHeading()` method of Google maps Geometry Library on your current location and the points. Then you can adjust those values based on your current orientation.

Comment: I know my location in latitude/longitude and I know the distance in meters between the markers and my position. But I don't know my orientation :s

Comment: This answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20340147) can help you get the device heading. Also edited my original answer. Its the `computeHeading()`method.

Comment: That's what I was looking for ! Now need to convert markers using this orientation.
I'll post the answer later during the day when I'll have it, thanks !